# Custom Navigation iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, mvvmcross

Im developing an app in xamarin for ios but the concept for native objective c is the same I believe. I want a container view that has a bar underneath a navigation bar that will be on all `UIViewControllers`. I went the container class way so I ddn't have to set up the bar on all pages. Is there another more efficient way of doing this? the bar will contain icons which will be updated by live events but are not click able e.g. wifi status but not the phones wifi.

I have managed to create a custom container view that has a navigation bar and the bar I want underneath it with a view wrapper for loaded in view controls. I have the navigation working for push but pop causes an error sometimes when push back to fast across multiple screens it just stops but the nav bar continues to go back. I have used the nav bar delegate for should pop etc but can't seem to find out why the timings are off.

If anyone can point me a direction to solve this or a different way of keeping the same templat eon all views it would be much appreciated. CHeers

Code Sample:

AppDelegate

```
 _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
 _window.RootViewController = new ContainerView();
```

ContainerViewController:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
        var loginView = this.CreateViewControllerFor(ContainerModel.Login) as UIViewController;

        _navController = new UINavigationController(loginView);
        _navController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, false);
        _navController.Delegate = new NavDelegate(navBar);

            containerView.AddSubview(_navController.View);
```

So navBar is from a manually added navigationbar in my xib file and containerView is where i want to show each viewcontroller in the containerview

Comment: Do you just have a navigation bar, or a navigation controller? You said you created a "custom container view", is this a view or a custom container controller?

Comment: The container class is a UIViewController which creates a new UINavigationController in the viewdidload method. The navigationbar is an outlet from one I had inserted to the xib file. This class is meant to act as a Custom Container Controller.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The navigationbar is an outlet from one I had inserted to the xib file". Did you add this navigation bar manually (as opposed to using the one you get with the navigation controller)?

Comment: Hi sorry, yeah I added it manually. I'll post some sample code

Comment: updated with basic code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xamarin, so I don't know if I'm reading your code correctly, but normally with a container view controller, you add another controller (the navigation controller in your case) as a child before adding its view as a subview. I don't know if this will fix your problem or not, but it should be done (as well as calling didMoveToParentViewController:).

Comment: Thanks for that I'll give that a go. The only reason I'm doing this is because I want all my UIViewControllers to have the same bar/view under the navigation controller without having to continously add them when I create a new one. Do you think there is a better option than what I am attempting to do currently?

Comment: Another approach you could take would be to not use a custom container controller, but have the navigation controller (with its own navigation bar) be the root view controller. Have all your view controllers inherit from a common ancestor which has the bar you want at the top of its view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a uiview in place of navigation bar which needs to be updated on every xib by making your navigation bar hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use storyboards, with the following structure?

```
- nav controller view
  - container view
    - nav controller view (hide/show nav bar as necessary)
      - content
```